# GDI+ large font size rendering and ClearType

Tags: c#, fonts, gdi+, cleartype

I'm trying to render large size font characters to a bitmap using GDI+ for later offline use (as a bitmap font for drawing text using Direct3D on Windows Phone, to be precise). I would like the font to be rendered using ClearType, but I seem to unable to do that when font size is larger than 48 points. Here's the code I'm using:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var noFontFallbackFormat = (StringFormat)StringFormat.GenericTypographic.Clone();
    noFontFallbackFormat.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.NoFontFallback;

    DrawCharacter("Segoe UI", 48, noFontFallbackFormat);
    DrawCharacter("Segoe UI", 72, noFontFallbackFormat);
}

static void DrawCharacter(string fontName, float fontSize, StringFormat stringFormat)
{
    var fontSizeInPixels = fontSize * 96.0f / 72.0f;  // Converts points to pixels

    using (var font = new Font(fontName, fontSizeInPixels, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
    {
        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(256, 256, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        {
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

                var text = "A";
                var characterSize = graphics.MeasureString(text, font, Point.Empty, stringFormat);
                int width = (int)Math.Ceiling(characterSize.Width);
                int height = (int)Math.Ceiling(characterSize.Height);

                graphics.Clear(Color.Black);
                graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, stringFormat);
                graphics.Flush();

                using (var characterBitmap = bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
                {
                    characterBitmap.Save(string.Format("{0}_{1}.png", fontName, fontSize));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When rendered using font size 48, it looks like this:

[image: Segoe UI_48]

However, rendering with font size 72 makes ClearType disappear:

[image: Segoe UI_72]

Why is this the case? I know TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit is a hint and not an order, but can I somehow force it to use ClearType all the time?

Comment: Setting the font rendering to AntiAliasGridFit might look better than ClearType at larger font sizes.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, though I still wonder why ClearType refuses to work.

Comment: Different fonts switch over at different sizes. How do you know when to use AntiAliasGridFit?